# "Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes" in Gradle Build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

i have a project with a library in libs folder.

When i run the app the android studio is give this Error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

And app doesn't Run, what is the problem?
i run this app on android studio 1.2 in windows and that is fine but in android studio 1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Openjdk 1.7 i have Error. 
Any way to fix this?

this my Directories:

[image]

here app Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.vtj.Myapp"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(":sundate")
compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidviewhover:library:1.0.4@aar'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
}
```

And Here Sundate Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

And Settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':sundate'
project(':sundate').projectDir = new File('libs/sundate')
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error?

Comment: i update all library, and use another library for this situation.